# paypal one time login during paypal payment

Tags: paypal

I need a help regarding paypal.
That is. Once I have logged in with paypal and made payment, Then for another payment no login will be asked, Direct payment will be done using paypal. Please comment your suggestions. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options for this.

First, you could take a look at [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/), which is part of the [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) platform.  It allows users to create a Preapproval profile that your application can then use to trigger payments at any time without further approval as long as the payment fits within the guidelines of the preapproval profile.

Another option would be to look into [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) with [Reference Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/). This would give you a little bit more flexibility and would be more in line what you're asking for, I think.  Users would agree during their first payment with you to allow you to auto-charge this same account in the future.  Then you would use [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) to trigger future payments based on that "billing agreement" which is what it would be called that way.

I would recommend going with Express Checkout, and you might want to look at [Digital Goods](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntroducingExpressCheckoutDG/), too, which just adds some more functionality with quicker PayPal checkout in various ways.

It's all handled through a few simple API calls, so don't let all the info scare you.

[My PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) will make all of the API calls very simple for you regardless of which method you choose.  Again, though, I'd recommend Express Checkout.